# Right way to run a MultiWord job on a Chainlink Test Node

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, chainlink

I am trying to setup a job for a Chainlink MultiWord response on my local test node, using the documentation's example job spec [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/multi-variable-responses/). Just would need confirmation that the address param:

```
"params": {
    "address": "0xc57b33452b4f7bb189bb5afae9cc4aba1f7a4fd8"
  }
```

is the one for my oracle contract address right? Also, where on the smart contract for the API call should I then specify the jobId and the oracle address to use?

Answer (score 1):

found this answer, posting it here in case others find it useful - basically yes should use the Oracle contract address with valid on-chain setFulfillmentPermissions. Also, when declaring the "specID" param:

```
bytes32 private specId;
```

Need to make sure that the jobID copied over from the Chainlink node is encoded as bytes32 object, not as a string.